# Programmatically created AWS EC2 Instances not showing up in browser

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

This might be a only-for-me problem. I am using eclipse with AWS plugin to tryout AWS EC2 Instances. The instances are successfully launched through program, I get the list of running Instances' ids.

The problem is i launched three instances and they are not showing up in the running instances in the browser, although it shows in the eclipse console:

```
#5 Describe Current Instances
You have 3 Amazon EC2 instances
i-801cc37a running
i-fb1ec101 running
i-bc1cc346 shutting-down
```

[image]

This is the code I am using to create AWS Instance:

```
final String imageId = "ami-76f0061f";
int maxInstance = 1, minInstance = 1;

RunInstancesRequest rireq = new RunInstancesRequest(imageId, minInstance, maxInstance);
RunInstancesResult rires = ec2.runInstances(rireq);
List<Instance> insres = rires.getReservation().getInstances();

String createdInstanceId = null;
for(Instance ins: insres) {
    createdInstanceId = ins.getInstanceId();
    System.out.println("New Instance has been created: " + ins.getInstanceId());
}
```

**(** There was a problem I was facing; The ImageId was given to me by my professor which is not present in the list of images in the aws.amazon website for my region. However, only this works. I got two Ids from the website for my region, but they ended up with `InvalidAMIID.NotFound` error. I even tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543071). This might be relevant to not showing up in browser as the ImageId is not in my region... **)**

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong? Or is this pretty normal. If it is normal, is there anyway to make the 'programmatic' instances to show up in browser. If the ImageIds are the problem can I please know how to fix it? I assure that the region in eclipse and aws website are same: oregon(us-west-2).

Thank you

Comment: If you are indeed using AMI `ami-76f0061f`. Its only available in us-east-1. That particular AMI is somewhat out of date. You can get current versions here: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Comment: @datasage, but nothing else seems to work, I mean from my region oregon. As I mentioned I get `InvalidAMIID.NotFound`, Does using instance out of your region end in showing inthe list of instances in the browser? I am new please explain.

Comment: Your SDK code is connecting to us-east-1. Which is why you can't find any other AMI's. This page explains how to set your region: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html

Comment: @datasage is this the same reason for the instance not to show up in the browser?

Comment: Correct, You are viewing resources in US-West-2 (Oregon). You are creating resources in US-East-1 (N. Virginia). Each region in AWS is isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the region in your console. Based on your screenshot it is set to `"Oregon"`. Change it to `"N. Virginia"` and you should be all set.

Comment: This works, but please explain, why can't I create a instance from my region? The region in eclipse config is Oregon, the IAM console is in Oregon, I get the list of available images from Oregon, yet I am not able to connect! I get `InvalidAMIID.NotFound` error, for example I used `ami-dfc39aef`

Comment: Never mind, thanks a lot for your help. The link from @datasage fixed it: `ec2.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));`. And yours answers the OP :)